# How to make a function return a list of indices of the characters in the second string that appears in the first string?

Tags: python

```
def get_indices_from_the_second_string(string1, string2):
    '''(str, str) -> list of int
    >>> get_indices_from_the_second_string('AGTACACGTTAC', 'GAATTC')
    [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11]
    >>> get_indices_from_the_second_string('AGTACACGTTAC', 'GGATCC')
    [1, 7, 10]
    '''

    acc= []

    for i in range(0, len(string2)):
        for r in range(0, len(string1)):
            if len(acc) == len(string2):
                            break            
            if string1[r] == string2[i]:
                acc.append(r)
                i += 1
                r += 1
    return acc

    # the second example is wrong
    # how to make it not reversed only from left to right
    # maybe use find.()???
```

Comment: So, in your second example, we should just keep going through the whole string until we find the next instance of `G`? What if subsequent letters in `'GGATCC'` don't then exist after that point? i.e. after we find the second `G`, there is only one more `C` left in `string1` (`TTAC`) but `string2` contains _two_ instances of `C`

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_indices_from_the_second_string(string1, string2):
    acc = []
    s2_counter = 0
    for i, letter in enumerate(string1):
        if letter == string2[s2_counter]:
            acc.append(i)
            s2_counter += 1
            if len(acc) == len(string2):
                break
    return acc

a = get_indices_from_the_second_string('GAATTCCGTTAC', 'GAATTC')
```

Comment: when the example is ('GAATTCCGTTAC', 'GAATTC') the index is out of range...

Answer (score 0):

Remove lines

```
            i += 1
            r += 1
```

as `for` loops increase `i` and `r` automatically.

And then modify your code:

```
lower = 0                             # from this index will be string1 searched

for i in range(0, len(string2)):
    for r in range(lower, len(string1)):
        if string1[r] == string2[i]:
            acc.append(r)
            lower = r + 1             # indexes from 0 to r are already used
            break
        elif r == len(string1) - 1:   # last index did not match
            return acc
return acc
```

Comment: yes ..but the second example will return [1, 7, 10, 1, 3, 8]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see what you're doing.

```
def get_indices_from_the_second_string(string1, string2):
    acc = []
    string1_index = 0
    for char in string2:
        while string1[string1_index] != char:
            string1_index += 1
            if string1_index >= len(string1):
                return acc
        acc.append(string1_index)
        string1_index += 1
        if string1_index >= len(string1):
            return acc
    return acc
```

Comment: when ('GAATTCCGTTAC', 'GAATTC')

Comment: the answer is [0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5]
but it should be [0,1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: The first version I posted didn't advance after finding a match.  Refresh your page to see my update

Answer (score -1):

Use the built in function `zip`, along with another built in `enumerate`

```
acc = []
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(string1, string2)):
    if a==b:
        acc.append(i)
return acc
```

Comment: I can't get this to work, did you test with the example inputs commented in `get_indices_from_the_second_string` comments?

Comment: Actually, I'm not clear on how the question inputs map to the expected outputs tbh

Comment: @Jarin could you write out what you're trying to do a little more explicitly? I thought you were trying to find a list of the indices where the two strings share a character, but that doesn't actually match the examples you gave.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh actually, it looks like it's sequential with the indexing. So, in searching for the second `G` in the second example, it skips over ~2/3 of the string.

Comment: The first parameter is a string with random letters. The second parameter is a letter sequence. Return a list of all the indices where the letter sequence occurs in the first string. Only look from left to right.

Comment: for example if the first string = 'ABCBAAAA'  the second string = 'CBA'

Comment: the list should return [2,3,4]