# Return the indices where all the second string occurs in the first string

Tags: python

```
def abc(a, b):
    '''(str, str) -> list of int

>>> abc('ABCDEAADFET', 'ABCDE')
[0，1，2，3，4，5]
>>> abc('ABCDEAADFEABCDET', 'ABCDE')
[0，1，2，3，4,10,11,12,13,14]
>>> abc('SDFECAADFET', 'ABCDE')
[]


# how to do this ? especially the second case
# use a.find.()
```

Comment: >>> abc('ABCDEAADFET', 'ABCDE')                                                                     [0，1，2，3，4，5]

Comment: >>>abc('ABCDEAADFEABCDET', 'ABCDE')                                                   [0，1，2，3，4,10,11,12,13,14]

Comment: Is this the same as your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224680/how-to-make-a-function-return-a-list-of-indices-of-the-characters-in-the-second/40225024?noredirect=1#comment67714826_40225024

Answer (score -1):

Simple way to do it will be by creating a function as:

```
def my_function(my_string, my_substring):
    len_substring = len(my_substring)
    my_index = []
    for i in range(len(my_string)-len_substring+1):
        if my_string[i:i+len_substring] == my_substring:
             my_index.extend(range(i, i+len_substring))
    return my_index
```

*Explanation:*

Iterate your string to check the match for substring. If there is a match, add the corresponding indexes to the list.

Sample Run:

```
>>> my_function('ABCDEAADFET', 'ABCDE')
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> my_function('ABCDEAADFEABCDET', 'ABCDE')
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
>>> my_function('SDFECAADFET', 'ABCDE')
[]
```